# Unity 2019.2.9f1 Crashes on MacOS Mojave

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash, macos-mojave

My unity project is randomly crashing at the startup. I was used to solving the problem by checking out my source code in an alternative location and adding the project back to Unity Hub. Unfortunately, this solution no longer works. 
Here the crashlog:

```
Process:               Unity [11340]
Path:                  /Applications/2019.2.9f1/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity
Identifier:            com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x
Version:               Unity version 2019.2.9f1 (2019.2.9f1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        Unity Hub [740]
Responsible:           Unity [11340]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2019-12-07 17:07:08.386 +0000
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.14.5 (18F132)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     3.5 (16P5125)

Time Awake Since Boot: 36000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       10000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  CrBrowserMain  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000000002c0
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0x2c0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010c8e4000-00000001135bc000 [108.8M] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/2019.2.9f1/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: CrBrowserMain  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff6f3332c6 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff6f3eebf1 pthread_kill + 284
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff6f29d6a6 abort + 127
3   com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x000000010f899dfe HandleSignal(int, __siginfo*, void*) + 62
4   libmonobdwgc-2.0.dylib          0x0000000147111619 mono_chain_signal + 79
5   libmonobdwgc-2.0.dylib          0x0000000146fe2c7f mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 414
6   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00007fff6f3e3b5d _sigtramp + 29
7   ???                             000000000000000000 0 + 0
8   com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x00000001102d6e71 LightingDataAsset::GetLightingDataAssetStableID(UnityScene*) + 97
9   com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x0000000110344c2f WriteLightingDataAssetJob::Prepare(dynamic_array<UnityGUID, 0ul>&) + 719
10  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x0000000110268bf3 IssueWriteLightingDataAssetJob(JobManager*, dynamic_array<UnityGUID, 0ul>&, Hash128 const&) + 531
11  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x000000011026dd31 LightingDataAssetManager::PostUpdate() + 353
12  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x000000011024f75c gi::PostUpdate(dynamic_array<GISceneManagerClient*, 0ul> const&) + 44
13  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x0000000110284b55 GISceneManager::Update() + 1605
14  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x0000000110282d0a GISceneManager::GISceneManager()::tickGIInEditorRegistrator::Forward() + 74
15  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x000000010cd6ea62 CallbackArray::Invoke() + 82
16  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x000000010d5acb8f ProfilerCallbackInvoke<CallbackArray, &(GlobalCallbacks::tickGIInEditor)>::Invoke(char const*) + 63
17  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x000000010d5aa1a9 Application::TickTimer() + 4873
18  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x00000001108c5675 -[EditorApplication TickTimer] + 165
19  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff45579ceb __NSFireTimer + 80
20  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff432eca60 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
21  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff432ec60c __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 851
22  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff432ec152 __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 330
23  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff432cd362 __CFRunLoopRun + 2130
24  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff432cc8be CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 455
25  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff425b896b RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
26  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff425b86a5 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 603
27  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff425b8436 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
28  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff40952987 _DPSNextEvent + 965
29  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff4095171f -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1361
30  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff4094b83c -[NSApplication run] + 699
31  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff4093ad7c NSApplicationMain + 777
32  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x00000001109038a9 EditorMain(int, char const**) + 665
33  com.unity3d.UnityEditor5.x      0x0000000110903b79 main + 9
34  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff6f1f83d5 start + 1
```

what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to delete the `/library` folder inside the Unity Project and re-load the project